# Kendo Grid - Background color bleeds over radius on alt rows

Tags: html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, css

I am using the Kendo grid with no footer or scroll bar.  The problem I am running to is that the rounded corners get overrun by the alt row background color.  I want to keep the rounded corner as they match a number of other design elements on our page.

I'm not sure this is a Kendo issue as I can reproduce it without kendo.  [Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AS9f6/).  Perhaps it is Kendo's rendering of the html/css.

Any thoughts?  As we are using Kendo I can hack the html post kendo rendering for a quick solution but ultimately I would love to see Kendo fix this.

Here is my simple example.  I am mimicking the html rendered by the Kendo Grid.

```
<div style="width:400px;border-radius:20px;border:1px solid red;">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>blah</td><td>more blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color:lightblue;">
            <td>blah</td><td>more blah</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not a kendo problem, but a pretty common CSS problem.

One way of solving it is by  adding `overflow:hidden;` in the div container.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexyu/7VsgE/). You can apply this onto the content div of kendoGrid with the following css:

```
.k-grid-content {
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I would agree that this is not specifically a kendo problem but I would think that they could solve it without me having to do anything.  That being said, thanks for the response.  This was what I was looking for.